# Curl error with selenium

Tags: php, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught 
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for 
http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities": 
{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY"}}
```

I have got this error. Platform Linux, OS Ubuntu 16.04. Php script:

```
require_once    '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php';
$host = 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub';
$driver = \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create($host, 
\Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::firefox());
print_r($driver);
```

I have been installed Google Chrome latest version and chromedriver latest version for linux 64.

I was run selenium with this code:

```
DISPLAY=:99 xvfb-run -a -n 1 -l -s "-screen 0, 1024x768x8" java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/var/www/html/chromedriver-linux" -jar /var/www/html/selenium-server.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix error:

```
$options = new 
\Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions();
$options->addArguments(array(
    '--no-sandbox',
));
```

Also I changed webdriver to 2.29 and put it into /usr/local/bin with executable permission.

I changed running Xvfb to

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 -ac &
```

And than

```
export DISPLAY=:99 && java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver-229" -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server.jar
```

Now, it working good.